# Error when the proxy code class is added to the project

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, asmx, proxy-classes

I have a project was created in *framework 3.5* and the proxy class was created using wsdl.exe.

I am trying to change the *framework to 4.0* of the service class which was in *framework 3.5* and use same and created a proxy class using wsdl.

I tried to extend the proxy class and i am getting an error saying "`the type of namespace XXX could not be found`".

The technology used was the asmx earlier. The project that uses this service first was in .net 3.5 but now i changed that also to .net 4.0. I have referenced the same dll "service.dll" for the framework 4.0 and also using the `Microsoft.Web.Services3`.

Summary: I am trying to change the framework of both the projects(Service and the MyApplication) and integrate the proxy class generated from the wsdl.exe.
How can I resolve this issue?

I am using .net c# 4.0.

Comment: You are using [WSE][http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms977317.aspx], you may be missing the appropriate installer. Please install WSE and do the required configuration.

Comment: @VinayPandey- how to install it? the link says "Content Not found"

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project with framework 4.0 with the same name and then integrated with proxy class.